# Difference between ARM and Intel?

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi

"Technically, however, they represent different philosophies: the ARM architecture is designed to be as simple as possible, to keep energy wastage to a minimum, whereas Intel's range uses a more complex design that benefits from compatibility with the company's (much more power-hungry) desktop and laptop CPUs." Well then why can't I run Windows on a raspberry Pi? Also, what is `start4.elf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft seems to know there are issues with Windows on ARM because it won't even sell you a copy of it. The company licenses the ARM version only to OEMs to pre-install on new systems. When asked if it would open up sales so people could run Windows on the new Macs, Microsoft said it had no plans at this time.

Start4.elf is a file that raspberry pi uses to boot.

Hope this helps!